# generic form for Seblod (joomla 2.5 )

Tags: forms, button, joomla2.5

I'm a developer who has taken over a Joomla website, which was creatied using SEBLOD. The website is a listings website, which has over 300 listings on.

The purpose of the website is to get enquiries through the listsings.

Currently, the queries are attached to a button - which opens your email program and sends the email. This is not ideal.

Is there a way to create and attach a generic enquiry box or form to each listing, and include the name of the listing in this form when its sent?

Is there a way to create a form that can be attached on the frontend of the website page intead of 
the "Request a quote" button.

Answer (score 1):

To be candid, seblod is an impressive Joomla app, but I'm afraid you might not be able to get useful answers than on their forum, I've been using it now for over a year and I'm just coming to terms with some of its functionality. Visit the [forums](http://www.seblod.com/support/forum.html) and you should be able to find a good answer from the devs there. Its an expansive suite so it might give some unique challenges.